# How do I obtain rate estimates with 95% CIs for each level of a factor from a Poisson regression in R?

Tags: r, glm, poisson

I am running a Poisson regression model in R structured the following way:

```
mod <- glm(outcome ~ X + A + B + C + offset(log(time)), data = dat, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

Where `X` is my 2-level factor of interest and `A`, `B`, and `C` are additional covariates.

How can I extract rate estimates and 95% CIs for each level of `X` from `mod`?

My anticipated output would be:
Estimated rate for X_level1 (95% CI)
Estimated rate for X_level2 (95% CI)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you mean the *marginal* effect of `X` on `outcome`, that is, the estimated value of `outcome` at each of the two levels of `X` when all the other covariates are held at their mean values. To do this you could use the `emmeans` package:

```r
library(emmeans)

mod <- glm(outcome ~ X + A + B + C + offset(log(time)), 
           data = dat, family = poisson(link = "log"))

result <- as.data.frame(emmeans(mod, specs = 'X'))

result <- cbind(result[1], exp(result[2]), 
                CI = paste(round(exp(result[[5]]), 3),
                           round(exp(result[[6]]), 3), sep = '-'))
```

Giving you

```r
result
#>        X   emmean              CI
#> 1 level1 107.5459 104.587-110.589
#> 2 level2 147.1999 143.957-150.516
```

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(X = factor(sample(c('level1', 'level2'), 100, TRUE)),
                  A = sample(100)/5,
                  B = sample(100)/2, 
                  C = sample(100)/4, 
                  time = 1:100)

dat$outcome <- with(dat, rpois(100, 50 * as.numeric(X) - A + B - C + time))

head(dat)
#>        X   A    B     C time outcome
#> 1 level1 5.6 45.5 19.50    1      85
#> 2 level2 9.6 15.5  9.25    2      94
#> 3 level1 6.6 36.0 10.75    3      94
#> 4 level1 9.0 18.0 20.25    4      43
#> 5 level2 4.2 24.5  0.25    5     137
#> 6 level1 6.2 20.5 22.50    6      31
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your response! This seems to work, although when I try it with just X as a covariate, I would expect the emmean for the reference group to be aligned with the coefficient for the intercept in the original model; however, that isn't the case. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: It _is_ the same as the intercept, except that I have exponentiated it because you have a log link function, so the model's intercept is the _log_ of the expected value for the reference group. Try `emmeans(mod, specs = 'X')` and you will see that this is the same emmean as the raw model.

Comment: Sorry, no I understand that piece. Using your data example, if I cut out everything but X:set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(X = factor(sample(c('level1', 'level2'), 100, TRUE)),
                  #A = sample(100)/5,
                  #B = sample(100)/2, 
                  #C = sample(100)/4, 
                  time = 1:100)

dat$outcome <- with(dat, rpois(100, 50 * as.numeric(X) + time))

mod <- glm(outcome ~ X + offset(log(time)), 
           data = dat, family = poisson(link = "log"))

result <- as.data.frame(emmeans::emmeans(mod, specs = 'X')).

Comment: The intercept coefficient is 0.72 but the emmeans are 4.646 and 4.984

Comment: @JordanHackett you still have `time` in your model and haven't it into account. You would need to add `log(mean(dat$time))` to the coefficients to get the `emmeans` values. If you do `log(mean(dat$time)) + 0.7350 + c(0, 0.3208)` you will see this is the same as the emmeans results. (Or remove `time` from the model, in which case emmeans will match the model output directly)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I discovered that setting offset = 0 in the emmeans call gave me the desired result :)!